# How to troubleshoot Unexpected Execution Error in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I am receiving an Unexpected Execution Error in my query result and was wondering how I would better understand the error. What does Unexpected Execution Error mean?

```
{
   "errors":[
      {
         "message":"Unexpected Execution Error",
         "locations":[
            {
               "line":2,
               "column":3
            }
         ],
         "path":[
            "createProfile"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "data":{
      
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the failing query? Otherwise it's hard to help. But it seems the error is showing you the problem location.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue. This is a generic error message if there is a syntax or functional error in your query.